# Adding loop for multiple tickers in TDA-API python script

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I've managed to piece together the following code, and am wondering how to reference multiple tickers instead of only 'AAPL'. I'm new to python and have starting making some traction, but I'm scratching my head here. Thanks!

```
from tda import auth, client
import json
import config
import pandas as pd
import datetime

try:
    c = auth.client_from_token_file(config.token_path, config.api_key)
except FileNotFoundError:
    from selenium import webdriver
    with webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/capnb/Documents/TDAmeritrade/chromedriver') as driver:
        c = auth.client_from_login_flow(
            driver, config.api_key, config.redirect_uri, config.token_path)

r = c.get_option_chain('AAPL')
data = json.loads(r.text)

ret = []
for date in data["callExpDateMap"]:
    for strike in data["callExpDateMap"][date]:
        ret.extend(data["callExpDateMap"][date][strike])
for date in data["putExpDateMap"]:
    for strike in data["putExpDateMap"][date]:
        ret.extend(data["putExpDateMap"][date][strike])
df = pd.DataFrame(ret)
for col in ("tradeTimeInLong", "quoteTimeInLong", "expirationDate", "lastTradingDay"):
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], unit="ms")
filename = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('option_prices-%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M.csv')
path = "c:/Users/capnb/Desktop/"
    
df.to_csv(path+filename)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think you can call more than one symbol at a time, so create a list of tickers and loop. see if this works.

```
def get_chains(symbol):
    r = c.get_option_chain(symbol)
    data = json.loads(r.text)

    ret = []
    for date in data["callExpDateMap"]:
        for strike in data["callExpDateMap"][date]:
            ret.extend(data["callExpDateMap"][date][strike])
    for date in data["putExpDateMap"]:
        for strike in data["putExpDateMap"][date]:
            ret.extend(data["putExpDateMap"][date][strike])
    df = pd.DataFrame(ret)
    for col in ("tradeTimeInLong", "quoteTimeInLong", "expirationDate", "lastTradingDay"):
        df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], unit="ms")
    # filename = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('option_prices-%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M.csv')
    filename = symbol + '-option_prices-' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M') + '.csv'
    path = "c:/Users/capnb/Desktop/"
        
    df.to_csv(path+filename)

symbols = ['AAPL', 'GE', 'TSLA']
for symbol in symbols:
    get_chains(symbol)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction with the list and loop. If I wanted to combine all into one dataframe instead of saving each symbol as a separate file, should I be approaching this with the pd.DataFrame.from_dict() function?

Comment: Instead of writing to csv use return df in your function and iteration that df goes into a list. Then use pd.concat. Search stackoverflow for combining data frames. Lots of examples how to write that loop and collect dfs. You can create a new question if you need help.